# Failed to connect to local IP from Android application

Tags: java, android

The client failed to establish a connection to the local address `localhost:3000`.

**The error encountered was:**

```
dial tcp [::1]:3000: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your localhost:3000 address to local IP address for example 192.168.1.15:3000 etc.
2. Your server and client must be in same network

Comment: Also is your server running wampserver etc?

Answer (score 0):

#### Emulator

On an emulator the localhost is accessible using the IP **10.0.2.2** .
So `localhost:3000` will be `10.0.2.2:3000` in your emulator.

#### Physical device

First of all you must be on the same network to be able to connect.

- Get the PC ip using `ipconfig` (windows) and `ip a` or `ifconfig` (linux)
- Connect to the PC localhost using it's ip. i.g `192.168.2.121:3000`
  (your firewall must be OK with this)

If you are trying to connect using code, same things are needed for this